# better implementation to pan a background image? this jquery is too jolty

Tags: jquery, image, css, background, pan

see the attached jsfiddle, with an panning animated background, so as to infinitely loop a panoramic photo on the background

Can you think of any implementations that are less jolty/much smoother?

```
<style>#image{
width:100%;
height:500px;
background-image: url("http://illustratedmaps.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Abi-Daker-London-360-panorama-copy1.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: center;
}</style>

<div id="image">.</div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://spritely.net/scripts/jquery.spritely-0.6.8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://spritely.net/scripts/jquery.spritely-0.6.8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>$('#image ').pan({fps: 30, speed: 0.5, dir: 'left'});</script>
```

Comment: Works ok for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nwhderey/

Comment: It is still Jolty, perhaps you can change the speed to 0.1 instead, and you will see the jumps..?
Or maybe its just that my screen is low res..? haha

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect.  When you change the speed to 0.1, you can see the image moving 1 pixel at a time.  That's what it does.  If your screen is low res, you will see larger jumps because the pixels are larger.  I'm not sure what else you expect it to do.  You could try a real CSS3 transition to see if it works any better.

Comment: See [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background) and [here](http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css) for tutorials on using CSS3 to do this.  There are many more examples if your search for "css3 background image movement".